# Get properties in Angular 2 using Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to make the property `fullName` display the first and the last name. How to make the get property to work?

See this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFg3la).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Person {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  get fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>My first name is {{person.firstName}}</p>
    <p>My last name is {{person.lastName}}</p>
    <h2>My full name is {{person.fullName}}!</h2>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Get property issue';
  person: Person = {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'This',
    lastName: 'That'
  };
}
```

**EDIT**
What I actually wanted to achieve was how to use get properties when calling a service and subscribing for the result. But I managed to figure it out based on below answers. Thanks!

See my updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtheWE)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`Working PLUNKER`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3KnPuuFDzfDHNHutuPL?p=preview)

Try this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Person {
  constructor(public id: number,public firstName: string, public lastName: string){}

  get fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>My first name is {{person.firstName}}</p>
    <p>My last name is {{person.lastName}}</p>
    <h2>My full name is {{person.fullName}}!</h2>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Get property issue';
  person: Person = new Person( 1, 'This', 'That');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the `Person` type:

```
constructor() {
  this.person = new  Person();
  this.person.id = 1;
  this.person.firstName = 'This';
  this.person.lastName = 'That';
}
```

In your case, the `person` property conforms to the `Person` type (at the structure level) but it's not actually an instance of the `Person` type since you define the object literally. This means that you need to define all the properties in your literal object and you won't be able to use the `fullName` getter since it's not part of this object. It's a kind of cast.

Use the following for convenience:

```
export class Person {
  constructor(public id: number,
     public firstName: string,
     public lastName: string) {
  }

  get fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

In this case, you can use the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Get property issue';
  person: Person = new Person(1, 'This', 'That');
}
```