# Calling typescript getter in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I would like to call a typescript property from angular2 template. I can't do that if I call the property of an object in a loop. If there is no loop, the code works fine.

[Calling method from a Angular 2 class inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37385535/124797) this question addresses the problem if there is no loop.

Please find the Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/c8uY12?p=preview) .

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

export class User {
  id: number;
  mail: string;
  created_at: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  deleted_at: any;

 // if I call {{user.name}} nothing gets printed.
 get name() {
    return "My name is:" + this.first_name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ion-list *ngFor="let user of users">
        <div>{{user.first_name}}</div>
    </ion-list>
  `
})
export class App {
  users: User[];
  constructor() {
    this.users = [ {first_name:"Jagan"}, {first_name:"Nath"}  ];
  }
}
```

**Update**

Here is a piece of code. Both working and not working version is given below.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';


export class User {

  first_name : string;

  get name() {
    return "Name:" + this.first_name;
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
       {{user.first_name}}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ MyComponent ]
})   

export class App {

  constructor() {
    let str = "{ \"first_name\" : \"Jagan\" }";
    this.user = JSON.parse(str) as User;
  }
}
```

// **This does not work.**

```
 /* @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
           {{user.name}}
        </div>
      `,
      directives: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

In your updated code you are just telling TypeScript that whatever JSON object you have now should be considered as a `User` object. TypeScript will happily parse that for you, but in runtime you don't actually have a `User` object, as demonstrated by the fact that you can't access the `name` method. You can inspect the object yourself by just printing it to console: `console.log(this.user)`. You will see it prints `Object {first_name: "Jagan"}`. That is clearly not a `User` object.

I would suggest to create a constructor on `User` that accepts a JSON parameter and have the `User` object configure itself with this JSON. I have created a Plunker for you to see the idea in action: [Plunker - updated](https://plnkr.co/edit/1zcSKd0cBon0soRzffA8?p=preview)

The `User` will get a constructor that accepts a JSON config (you could even type that if you want):

```
constructor(config: any) {
  this.first_name = config.first_name;
}
```

And when constructing the `User`, you pass along the configuration in its constructor:

```
let obj = { first_name: 'Jagan' };
this.user = new User(obj);
```

**ORIGINAL**

When you create a `new User` you should use a constructor to set the parameters of the new `User` object. In the current situation you are just pushing some new objects (not even `User` objects) onto the `users` array by typing `{first_name: "name"}`. You can check that out in your current code by printing the `users` array to your console (that is: `console.log(users)`).

I have created a Plunker with a constructor on `User`: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Jgi1RnlzIKg2AAe7w3g?p=preview).

The `User` will get a constructor:

```
 constructor(first_name: string) {
   this.first_name = first_name;
 }
```

And calling `new User` now expects a new argument, `first_name`:

```
this.users = [ new User("Jagan"), new User("Nath")  ];
```

Comment: Nope, I missed that, but I updated the answer now. The idea is still the same: use a constructor in User.

Comment: Looks like this works. I tested my plunker sample. It worked there. Most likely it will work in my application. Will test it once I go home. For time being, I accepted the answer. I understood the problem now.

Comment: The code worked. But forgot to let you know here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
this.users = [ {first_name:"Jagan"}, {first_name:"Nath"}  ];
```

typechecks because typescript is structural (more : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html) however it does not creates `User`. You need to `new User` to get the `get name` property

Comment: OK. I created that and now it calls the method / property. But I get this 
`My name is:undefined     My name is:undefined`

Comment: @Jagannath you've forgotten to set `first_name`

Comment: I am not sure. The actual scenario is a bit different though. I get data through a service in a JSON format. I parse it to an Object and then I bind them to the template. I can't set the members explicitly.